# Help me understand javascript:void(null)

Tags: javascript

can someone please help me with this javascript:void(null)
I found it used in link buttons as follows

```
<a onclick="ProcessResponse()" href="javascript:void(null)" >Accept Data</a>
```

Comment: Better worded as <a onclick="ProcessResponse(); return false;" href="http://example.com/real/url">. The return false will prevent the real url from being activated, but right-clicking the link and choosing open in new window will launch the URL instead of performing the action.

Comment: @Joeri and those with JavaScript disabled will still get something happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically what happens is the `onclick` the function `ProcessResponse()` is called and the `href` is set to `javascript:void(null)` to disable the ***default behaviour*** of the link.

Most developers are simply used to writing this too:

```
<a onclick="ProcessResponse(); return false;" href="#" >Accept Data</a>
```

**Example:**

Suppose we have this link in place:

```
<a onclick="ProcessResponse(); return false;" href="http://www.google.com" >Accept Data</a>
```

Note that `href` is set to `www.google.com` but when you actually click on that link, it would simply call the `ProcessResponse()` function and won't go to `www.google.com` because the `return false` put after `ProcessResponse()` disables the default behavior of the link that is going to `www.google.com`. Same is the case for the link you have posted.

Comment: This is technically incorrect.  It doesn't "disable the default behaviour of the link", it's more like having an empty link.  Try just `javascript:` or `javascript:undefined`.

Comment: @Andy E's head: I am talking about href set to #.

Comment: no, you're not.  Allow me to expand the quote - *`href` is set to `javascript:void(null)` to disable the default behaviour of the link*. - which is incorrect.  Does anyone else smell sock puppets?

Comment: @Andy E's head: I agree with sarfraz like others, whether it is empty or disabled. it boils down to the fact that the default action of link is changed/removed/disabled/emptied.

Answer (score 17):

`void` is a JavaScript operator but is sometimes mistaken for a function because of the common use of brackets that follow it.  The intended purpose of `void` is to evaluate an expression without returning a value.  Therefore, any expression at all can be `void`ed, it doesn't have to be `null` and quite often you see `void(0)` or less frequently, `void 0`.

When you use `javascript:` in a `href` attribute, the expression following will be evaluated and its result will be returned.  This can be seen by entering the following into your browser address box:

```
javascript:prompt("test");
```

Type anything into the box that appears and press enter/click ok.  You will notice that the page will disappear and whatever you typed will appear.  Now watch what happens if we add `void 0;`:

```
javascript:prompt("test"); void 0;
```

After clicking OK in the prompt, nothing happens.  That's `void 0`'s handywork, it returns `undefined` and so the browser does nothing about it.  This applies to `href` in links too (feel free to try it).  The whole thing could even just be written as `javascript:void prompt("test");`.

As others have mentioned, it's best to use `return false;` from an event handler rather than using `void` in the href.  In fact, it's recommended not to use `javascript:` in the `href` attribute at all.

Answer (score 4):

`javascript:void(null)` = do nothing.

Notice there is a javascript call in the onclick event handler - that does something (I'm guessing it accepts data by processing the response ;).

Answer (score 1):

Appending `void(0)` to javascript instructions is a common trick when you use a `javascript:` pseudo-URL to run code. If you omit doing this, and the script returns something other than *undefined*, it will be treated as if it was passed to `document.write` - that is, the browser will navigate away to an empty page.

There are valid applications for this trick (namely, bookmarklets should always end like this), but in the example you gave it is just wrong, for reasons already explained by others.