# Can I run arbitrary javascript code in the javascript:void() function using the browser's address bar?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if I could run a block of code(which includes for loops and if statements) in a javascript:void() function through the URL box.

Answer (score 3):

`void` isn't a function, it's an operator.  This means you can use it with or without parenthesis.  All it does is makes the expression following it return `undefined`.  In the case of navigation, returning `undefined` prevents the result of the expression from causing navigation away from the page.

You can run any JavaScript code through the address bar of some browsers, whether you use the `void` operator or not.  `void` just makes it safe to do so without navigating away.  A popular alternative to `void` is to wrap your code in a self executing anonymous function:

```
javascript:(function () { alert("hello"); })();
```

Often, snippets of code like this are saved as a bookmark so that they can be run at the click of a link in the bookmarks or favourites bar on any page.  These snippets are referred to as [Bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

The `javascript:` protocol has been disabled for URL entry in some newer browsers, most notably Firefox ([since 6.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656433)).  This is primarily to prevent users from being targets of self-XSS attacks, where they are convinced by a potential attacker to paste a `javascript:` URL in the address bar.  In Google Chrome and recent versions of Internet Explorer, the `javascript:` part is stripped from the pasted code.  These snippets still work as bookmarklets in all the above browsers, however.

You can read more about `void` in another answer I gave a while ago: [Help me understand javascript:void(null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863878/help-me-understand-javascriptvoidnull/2864019#2864019).

Comment: It won't work from the address bar (tested in IE 11 and Firefox 27.0.1). You have to save it as bookmark to make it work.

Comment: @Nolonar: I wasn't able to verify your comment for IE 11, since I'm away at the moment and only have Linux on my laptop.  I spent about 10 minutes searching the web and can only find references that indicate the same behaviour as Chrome (where the `javascript:` protocol is stripped when pasted).  I was able to verify this in Firefox, however.  I've updated the answer with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can run statements in url box.

like this:

```
javascript:if(2>1){alert('2 > 1');}
```